# Snapshot from under motorcycle - Oil leak related?

Tags: motorcycle, oil-change, oil-leak

first of all I am a complete newbie with regards to motorcycle and this is actually my first bike.

I own a Yamaha Vstar 950 tourer (2009), I changed oil last week. Today I parked at a shopping mall and spent an hour inside, when back I noticed a stain under my bike. I wiped it with my finger and it was oil, not sure if from my bike or the car which was parked before me.

I put a cardboard under the bike and will check it tomorrow morning to see if it is dropping oil, in the meantime I took this snapshot from under the bike.

This big patch in the picture, is it potentially related to oil leak? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this motor, the oil filter (the black cylinder) screws onto the crankcase, and is sealed to the crankcase with a rubber gasket built into the flat side of the filter. It looks like the gasket has leaked.

Rather than fussing with the gasket, I would drain the oil from the bike into a plastic tub, then replace the filter with a new one. Unscrew the old filter by rotating it CCW. Before screwing on the new filter, make sure the sealing surface on the crankcase is clean and smooth. Then moisten your finger with oil (the oil in the tub is fine for this) and rub it around the black gasket you'll find on the flat surface of the oil filer; the idea is to wet the gasket so it slides easily over the crankcase surface.

Then screw on the new filter. Turn it CW onto its threads, until it stops being easy to turn. Then turn it one-half turn more. That's about right: if you don't turn it enough, oil will leak; if you turn it too far, the gasket will deform and oil will leak and you won't be able to get the filter off next time.

THEN PUT THE OIL BACK IN THE MOTOR. Check that there's enough, there'll either be a dipstick or a small view window. You should be good to go.

Comment: Thx David. The thing is I changed oil and filter at the dealership, not myself. Seems they did a poor job, will ask them to fix it and will do it myself next time like you recommended.

Comment: Also try clean up the oil on the engine as well as you can (the stain may be impossible to remove - so just get the grit and drips off),  so you can see the "improvement" (no drips forming) after it's redone.